# Regex match either some pattern or predefined string

Tags: python, regex

I have two strings:

```
a = 'B E R L I N IS A CITY'
b = 'PARIS IS A CITY, TOO'
```

I want to match the first word in case it is with a single space, or a predefined word.

The regular expression I came up with (Python) is

```
regex = re.compile('^(?P<city>([a-z] )*|(paris )).*$', re.IGNORECASE)
print regex.match(a).group('city'), regex.match(b).group('city')
>>>> ('B E R L I N ', '')
```

`Paris` is not being matched. But when I turn around the regular expression,

```
regex = re.compile('^(?P<city>(paris )|([a-z] )*).*$', re.IGNORECASE)
print regex.match(a).group('city'), regex.match(b).group('city')
>>>> ('B E R L I N ', 'PARIS ')
```

`Paris` is being matched. What am I missing?

Comment: I think you meant 2 problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The “problem” is that `^([a-z] )*` matches the begin of the string `PARIS …` when the `[a-z]`  is repeated zero times. So there is no need for the regex interpreter to test for the literal `paris` .

Use `+` instead of `+` and it works as expected:

```
^(?P<city>([a-z] )+|(paris )).*$
```

Comment: Thats it! -> regex = re.compile('^(?P<city>([a-z] )+|paris ).*$', re.IGNORECASE)

Comment: re.I is enough, instead of re.IGNORECASE

Answer (score 2):

Use of `span()` often throws light on the problems,

```
import re

regex = re.compile('^(?:((?:[a-z] )*)|(paris )).*$', re.IGNORECASE)

a = 'B E R L I N IS A CITY'
b = 'PARIS IS A CITY, TOO'
for x in (a,b):
    print x
    print 'span(1)==',regex.match(x).span(1),'  span(2)==',regex.match(x).span(2)
    print
```

The result is:

```
B E R L I N IS A CITY
span(1)== (0, 12)   span(2)== (-1, -1)

PARIS IS A CITY, TOO
span(1)== (0, 0)   span(2)== (-1, -1)
```